# hyva-themes/magento2-cms-tailwind-jit not working issue

Tags: magento2, theme, hyva, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

```
In my Magento setup, I add a new Hyva extension called cms-tailwind-jit was not working.
```

- toggle-button on-off HTML content is not a change issue.
- Magento Version: 2.4.5
- I upgrade the module version but it is not working.
- If anyone has knowledge about it, then please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried magento2-cms-tailwind-jit but it is not working.
You can use Yireo_DumpCmsContent module and add the
content['../../../../../../../var/cms-output/**/*.html',] in your tailwind.config.js. Please run this command once cms page is created run bin/magento cms:dump
After that run npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer which will generate the tailwind css for CMS page.
**Note:Disable magento2-cms-tailwind-jit when using Yireo module**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.